# Can elementary OS running on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: system-installation

Can I install Elementary OS on my Raspberry Pi 3 model B?

I want to run it for MySQL and coding, thanks.

Comment: There is an unofficial build of Elementary OS for the Raspberry Pi 4 here: https://github.com/meisenzahl/elementary-os-unofficial/tree/master/hera/arm64/raspi4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Nope**, there is no current build of the operating system for ARM processors, though theoretically someone could build one. However, you can download ARM and Raspberry Pi-compatible builds of [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) and Debian ([Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)), the latter being the most popular. (elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, which is based on Debian.) You can track the wishlist request for an ARM version of elementary OS [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1629454).

Comment: https://github.com/meisenzahl/elementary-os-unofficial/tree/master/hera/arm64/raspi4

Comment: https://blog.elementary.io/elementary-os-on-raspberry-pi/